# How to remove values from a vector which are larger than previous values in the vector

Tags: r, data.table, processing-efficiency

I'm working with a large dataset (400M observations) of cars. Each entry has a VIN number, identifying it as a specific car. I group the dataset by VIN, so each group is 1 car (usually with multiple entries). I'm currently using the deployr package (I recently learned R using tidyverse).

I am trying to remove all observations where a vehicle **increases** in price as the car gets older (appreciates in value over time).

Let's look at 1 car as an example, I've removed all columns besides the relevant *data_year* (year in which the data was recorded) and *veh_price* (vehicle price) below:

```
ex_car <- structure(list(data_year = c(2003, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2012, 
2013, 2015), veh_price = c(2341, 50, 50, 100, 2600, 450, 3750, 
23000)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The columns are already sorted by data_year (descending order). As mentioned above, I am attempting to filter out any rows where the vehicle price **increases** from the **previous** row.

```
data_year     veh_price
2003          2341
2008          50            
2009          50            
2009          100           
2010          2600          
2012          450           
2013          3750
```

the desired output:

```
data_year     veh_price
2003          2341  
2008          50        
2009          50
```

I considered using `mutate` and `lead` to create a new row of the next value, calculating the difference, and then filtering all negative values (see below)

```
filtered_sample <- ex_car|> 
  mutate(
    next_price = lead(veh_price),
    diff_p = veh_price - next_price,
  ) |> 
  filter( diff_p >= 0)
```

However I'm concerned adding 2 columns is too inefficient to run on the large dataset. Is there a better, more efficient way of solving this problem? (I've heard data.table is optimized for larger operations, is there a way to use this package to do achieve the same goal?)

When I was first approaching this issue, I thought of iterating once through the vector, storing a temporary global `lowest_price` variable (initialized as the first value in the vector). if the next price is lower or equal (<=), set it as the new `lowest_price`, if it is greater (>), remove the value.

However, I couldn't figure out how to do this well in R.

Thanks for your time, please let me know if I failed to comprehensively describe the problem or if you need any more information.

Comment: Side note: how does `deployr` relate to this question?

Comment: I was just including the packages I had loaded, I'm still fairly new to R and still blurry on which functions I'm using are just base R vs added packages. This is my first question on stackoverflow so didn't want to get flamed for excluding any potentially important info.

Comment: There is a balance between *"tell us the packages you're using"* (so that we know which functions you are calling) and *"tell us every package that you load, regardless of use here"*. Sometimes extras can be perhaps red herrings or distracting (as here), sometimes they are the cause of problems (e.g., collisions and function masking). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: `x == cummin(.)` might be prone to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), a problem with tests of equality on high-precision floating point numbers. While not likely with *this* data, if the `price`-like variable has high precision and/or you want to be a bit safer in this regards, use @GregorThomas's suggested alternative of `diff(.) <= 0`, though this needs to be cumulative somehow:

```r
# dplyr
ex_car %>%
  group_by(VIN) %>%
  filter(cumall(c(TRUE, diff(veh_price) <= 0)))
# data.table
as.data.table(ex_car)[, .SD[c(TRUE, cumsum(diff(veh_price) > 0) == 0),], by = .(VIN)]
# base
ind <- with(ex_car, !!ave(veh_price, VIN, FUN = function(z) c(TRUE, cumsum(diff(z) > 0) == 0)))
ex_car[ind,]
```

---

We can use `cummin` here (relying on non-decreasing `data_year`). (This is for `cum`ulative `min`, not a mis-spelling of the spice cumin ;-)

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
ex_car %>%
  filter(veh_price == cummin(veh_price))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   data_year veh_price
#       <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1      2003      2341
# 2      2008        50
# 3      2009        50
```

Grouping by your `VIN`:

```r
ex_car %>%
  group_by(VIN) %>%
  filter(veh_price == cummin(veh_price))
### or with dplyr_1.1.0 or newer
ex_car %>%
  filter(veh_price == cummin(veh_price), .by = VIN)
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(ex_car)[ veh_price == cummin(veh_price),]
#    data_year veh_price
#        <num>     <num>
# 1:      2003      2341
# 2:      2008        50
# 3:      2009        50
```

Grouping by your `VIN`:

```r
as.data.table(ex_car)[ veh_price == cummin(veh_price), by = .(VIN)]
```

## base R

```r
ind <- with(ex_car, veh_price == cummin(veh_price))
ex_car[ind,]
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   data_year veh_price
#       <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1      2003      2341
# 2      2008        50
# 3      2009        50
```

Gropuing by your `VIN` requires the addition of `ave`:

```r
ind <- with(ex_car, ave(veh_price, VIN, FUN = function(z) z == cummin(z)))
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I would have used `all(diff(veh_price) <= 0)`

Comment: that's a great alternative! perhaps "safer" in the sense of R FAQ 7.31

Comment: @chrishtatu see the edit/update please ... likely not a big risk for your data, but noted nonetheless

Comment: thank you! `cummin` is quite handy in this instance (all integers, so no precision concerns), but I'll probably  use the diff solution when I expand into the whole dataset just to be safe!

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood - I thought OP wanted to filter out cars that showed any increases, not just the increase rows.

Comment: no worries, it's a good point and I adapted to the OP, thanks!